# Highres icon is 128px but submission is rejected

Tags: store, outlook-web-addins, office-store

Submission reject reason is:

1120.3.6.40  High Resolution Icon - Mail Add-Ins

The image file referenced by the HighResolutionIconURL link must be 128 × 128 pixels.

Your icon Height is: 120. Your Icon Width is: 120.

This is my manifest file:
https://www.outlix.no/api/outlix.xml
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is a point in time test; the validation tests are carried out against the manifest submitted at that time. Any updates or changes made to the manifest after submission are not reflected in the validation tests. If you change the manifest or a URL in the manifest you must resubmit your offer.